# Why does conda want to install the wrong version of gast with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'm getting gast errors when running Tensorflow 2.4.1 with gast 0.4.0.  This is the way conda installed it.  When I asked the TF people about it,

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48889

I was told to use gast 0.3.3.  However, conda will not allow this and wants to downgrade to TF 2.2. Where is the disconnect?  Are the TF devs responsible for proving conda dependencies, or do the conda people somehow do that themselves?  My guess is the former.

Comment: Have you tried to just use `pip install` to re-install the correct version?

Comment: In the same github you linked, the answer is already given. Conda is not officially supported by tensorflow, i.e. the tensorflow devs are not directly responsible for the conda package

Comment: I'm confused.  Do conda devs dream up their own dependencies for all the packages?  It seems that the devs of individual packages must specify their dependencies.

Comment: @Mastiff You might be able to figure out what is going on with the dependencies [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock).

Comment: "*do conda devs dream up their own dependencies [...]?* They set them, but usually in reference to what the package authors note. Getting them right is usually a feedback loop of community filing bug reports and then adjusting. The **anaconda** channel build has pegged `gast>=0.4.0` in their `tensorflow-base=2.4.1` build for linux, py37, with gpu. So, probably needs [an anaconda-issues bug report](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues).